# variable-length array of inputs in a variable-length javascript form

Tags: javascript

I want to create a javascript form that basically has a bunch of text input boxes. But I want the number of boxes to be the value of some variable, and I would like the id's or the names of the boxes to be elements in one array.

Actually, any solution to the following problem would be great. I have some variable x, and if x=10 then the form will be ten text input boxes, and at the end of the day (when the user clicks on the button to say "I've finished filling in these boxes now") I can create an array of length 10 whose entries are the contents of the ten text input boxes. But if x was 3 then there would be three text input boxes and I end up with an array of length 3 etc etc.

My current work-around, which is awful, currently involves 50 text input boxes, with names box01 to box50, and then 50 lines of the form a[1]=box01 a[2]=box02 etc etc, and the user can just leave all the ones he's not interested in blank. But I would imagine that something more streamlined is possible!

Comment: You can create input elements dynamically in a loop...

Comment: Right. Somehow that's not the problem. The problem I have is labelling the elements. Can I do NAME="blah[i]" somehow for i my looping variable?

Comment: Sure. If you create the input element with `var input = document.createElement('input');`, you can do `input.name = 'blah[' + i + ']';`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought I'd tried that and it had failed. Must try harder :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create the textboxes:

```
var x = 10,
    str = '';
while (x) {
  str = str + '<input type="text" name="box[]" id="box' + x + '">';
  x = x - 1;
}
```

Then you have a string `str` which you can insert in to the DOM. Because the name attribute is an 'array' (the square brackets mean "the value of this input is an element of the box array").

On the server side, you can then loop through this array. [In PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays):

```
foreach ($_POST['box'] as $box) {
  // do something with the input value
}
```

The `foreach` will loop through `$_POST['box']` (which is an array, because we used those square brackets), and you can do whatever you like with each box value inside the loop.

Comment: I see what I was apparently missing now: I didn't have name="box[]". I'm not quite sure I understand the logic but I can now try this and perhaps ask a more specific question if I can't get it to work. Thanks.

Comment: Saying `box[]` means "add an element to the end of the array `box`". If the above answers your question, click the tick underneath the up/down voting arrows.